# performing operations on blocks of data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this huge text file with data inside it that I want to reorder in a new format.

```
*******unwanted headers********
results
- 
1 2 3 4 3 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 2 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 1 6 7 8
1 2 3
-
-
1 2 3 4 3 6 7 8
2 2 3 4 2 6 7 8
1 2 3
-
2 2 3 4 3 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 2 6 7 8
1 2 3
1 2 3
-
```

Input is in format: N, X, Y, E, T, x, y, z

I want to do the following:

1. Ignore header lines
2. loop each block (one block is any successive lines with length = 8)
3. sort T column from lowest to highest
4. look at N column and check if there is 1 in the first line followed by 2 in the following line (applied only to the lines of length 8)
5. get z, y, x, E of the two lines
6. repeat steps 3, 4, and 5 for each block
7. output should be in format: z1 y1 x1 E1 z2 y2 x2 E2

This means that my code should not report a result from the first two blocks because they do not fulfil the conditions I set, but the third block will report a result.

Note: the data are floats, not integers.

I have tried this code but it is not working:

```
import fileinput
for Line in fileinput.input():
    Line = Line.split()
    if Line == '- ':
        continue
    if len(Line) == 8:
        'apply the conditions'
        continue
    if len(Line) != 8:
        break
```

Comment: I suggest you to use pandas library to solve this problem. For details https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am trying pandas. Hopefully, I can get it.